# Views -> add relationships: why can't I find Taxonomy term:parent?

Tags: views

I am trying build a list of children taxonomy terms, and I don't understand why I can't find this **Taxonomy term:parent** in the Views UI relationships section.

Any hint is welcome

Drupal 7, Views 3

**EDIT**: 
I was finally able to add the Taxonomy term: parent term relationship by adding first the content: taxonomy terms on node relationship.
Now I am trying to have unique results: for now the view displays one term for each node which cause duplicates.

[image]

Comment: One of the first choices in creating a View is picking the base table, which one do you have, and which other relationships have you already added?

Comment: Hello Letharion, I was finally able to pick **Taxonomy term:parent** by adding first **Content: Taxonomy terms on node**. But now I have a list of childs terms with duplicate (1 term for every exisiting node). Do you know how I could solve this? I have edited my question with the Views capture

Comment: From your question, I interpret that you only want to list terms, and don't care about the nodes? Then you shouldn't base your View on the node table, but on the term table instead.